# CSS how to set margin-top with using Auto

Tags: javascript, html, css

ho can I make an element be centered horizontally with auto and set margin-top or bottom to a fixed size?

the below seems to to work for me:

```
.class {
margin: auto;
margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: You are missing the HTML code, plus it's unclear what the "problem" is.  What is the issue?

Comment: It works just fine ...  and you can do like this instead: `margin: 100px auto 0 auto;`, which says 100px from top, auto on left and right, 0 on bottom ... and you can drop the last `auto` as well

Comment: Learn the margin "shorthand" variants: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin

Comment: Voted to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced_

Answer (score 1):

To set a fixed margin value to the top or bottom parameter you can do so by using the following format:

```
.class { 
    margin: 100px auto 100px auto;
}
```

The above is setting the top to 100px, then the right to auto, then bottom to 100px and then left to auto.

Comment: Code-only answers are not useful.  What does this do? Which property is which? Is there some authoritative documentation you can additionally link to?

Comment: margins and paddings in a one liner format take the values in the following order: TOP RIGHT BOTTOM LEFT

Comment: @Adrianopolis Yes, most of us know that, but where is that stated in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

It's even a bit simpler than in the previous answer: You can just write

```
.class { 
    margin: 100px auto;
}
```

or (if you need the margin-bottom to be 0)

```
.class { 
    margin: 100px auto 0;
}
```

If there are only two values, that's a shortcode for top+bottom and right+left margin. If there are three values, it's top - right+left - bottom.